# Return a variable from a begin rescue error

Tags: ruby, exception, return, nameerror, rescue

The method

```
def exp_backoff up_to, url, header = {}                                                                                      
  tries = 0                                                                                                                  
  begin                                                                                                                      
    tries += 1                                                                                                               
    response = JSON.parse(open(url, header).read)                                                                            

    return response                                                                                                          
  rescue OpenURI::HTTPError => e                                                                                             
    if tries < up_to                                                                                                         
      sleep( 2 ** tries )                                                                                                    
      retry                                                                                                                  
    else                                                                                                                     
      return e                                                                                                               
    end                                                                                                                      
  end                                                                                                                        
end
```

I'm calling `exp_backoff` expecting response to be returned, but it is not

```
  exp_backoff 2, status_url                                                                                                  
  session_token = response['session_token']
```

Getting this error

```
undefined local variable or method `response' for main:Object (NameError)
```

Comment: So your expectation is that something in the `begin` block to throw an exception, so that you'll hit the `rescue` block?  Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't assign return value to anything. This will work:

```
response = exp_backoff 2, status_url                                                                                                  
session_token = response['session_token']
```

Note however that your `rescue` part will return different object and `response['session_token']` will raise an undefined method error. Maybe you should rethink your method? Most likely, instead of returning exception object, you should simply reraise it:

```
rescue OpenURI::HTTPError                                                              
if tries < up_to                                                                                                         
  sleep( 2 ** tries )                                                                                                    
  retry                                                                                                                  
else                                                                                                                     
  raise                                                                                                       
end
```

Comment: Thanks caught the NoMethodError as well. I returned nil instead because it served my purposes better

Answer (score 0):

The local variable `response` you defined within the method `exp_backoff` is accessible only within the method body of `exp_backoff`. You cannot access it from outside of that method definition.

When you assign certain value to a local variable within a method and return that, the variable assignment has no effect to outside of the method.